# Convert 2 word16 to doubleword

Tags: vba, plc

A little background: I am writing a Visual Basic application.  It will connect to an Omron Programmable Logic Controller (PLC).

When I read data from the PLC, they come as WORDs (16bits).  However the PLC programmer needs to have a double-word (32bits) for a big number (bigger than what 16bits can hold).  I need to be able to show that number on the screen. As mentioned, I read from the PLC as WORDs.  So I can make 2 reads to get the 2 words.  However they are separate.

Here's what it is:  I need to show 120,000 on the screen (VB app).  on the PLC, I read 2 words (in bit form): 
Word#1: 1101 0100 1100 0000 (Unsigned, this equals 54464)

Word#2: 0000 0000 0000 0001

I need to put these together like this: 0000 0000 0000 0001 1101 0100 1100 0000 = 120,000

Are there any built in functions in Visual Basic that will combine these two 16bit words into into 1 Double-word?  If so what is it?

Or do I have to write a function to put these two values together?
Or has someone done something like this and can provide some info for me?

Comment: Actually, you could calculate value of word 2 and multiple by 65,536 and then add to word 1.  That should give you an accurate value.

Comment: that worked too.  What I found was the << and >> operands.  they shift bits left and right.  so I used the formula (Word2 << 16) to generate the value of Word2.  then added the value of Word1.

Answer (score 2):

I found the << and >> operands. They shift bits left and right. so I used the formula (Word2 << 16) to generate the value of Word2. then added the value of Word1.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA if you want to concatenate two strings together all you need to do is use the `&` operator. For example:

```
Dim TempCombinedWord as String

TempCombinedWord = FirstWord & LastWord
```

If `FirstWord` contained ***Happy*** and `LastWord` contained ***TreeFriends***.  Then `TempCombinedWord` would then contain ***HappyTreeFriends***.

Comment: The values are not words, they are numbers stored in 16-bit words.  I clarified my question.